# Sort elements based on their String property in case insensitive way

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, comparator, collectors

The following code works but it does take into account upper or lower case, and the result is a non alphabetically ordered list:

```
List<Pair<IContributionItem, String>> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();

Comparator<Pair<IContributionItem, String>> filePathComparator = Comparator.comparing(Pair<IContributionItem, String>::getPathToFile);
        itemsList = itemsList.stream().sorted(filePathComparator).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then I came across `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` so I tried to add it to it:

```
Comparator<Pair<IContributionItem, String>> filePathComparator = Comparator.comparing(Pair<IContributionItem, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER>::getPathToFile);
        itemsList = itemsList.stream().sorted(filePathComparator).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But it gives an error:
`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER cannot be resolved to a type.`

What would be solution or workaround to accommodate the code?

Comment: You should try with version `Comparator.comparing(function to element, comparator for that element)`. Something like `Comparator.comparing(Pair<IContributionItem, String>::getPathToFile, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);`. Take a look at example in documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function,java.util.Comparator)

Comment: @Pshemo that was exactly it, I followed your recommendation and it works now. You could post as an answer to the question so I could check your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Problem

When we use [`Comparator.comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U> keyExtractor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function)) elements are ordered based on value of key (object property) pointed out by `keyExtractor`. Sorting algorithm here uses the *natural* order defined by class of selected *key*.
Such class (or its ancestor) needs to implement `Comparable<T>` interface which forces implementation of `public int compareTo(T other)` method where comparison mechanism for sorting algorithms is defined.

Since your *keyExtractor* was extracting key of type String, the natural order defined in String class was applied, and that order is case-sensitive.

##### Solution

To build `Comparator` which will compare element based on its key (object property), but at the same time use different order than natural one for that key, we can use overloaded version of previous method, specifically [`Comparator.comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U> keyExtractor, Comparator<? super U> keyComparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function,java.util.Comparator)). Here the additiona/second parameter `keyComparator` allows us to pass different Comparator for selected key.

Since you claimed that

```java
Comparator.comparing(Pair<IContributionItem, String>::getPathToFile)
```

worked but in case-sensitive way, all you need to do is add `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` as *second* argument - the `keyComparator`

```java
Comparator.comparing(Pair<IContributionItem, String>::getPathToFile, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
                                                      // add this  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

##### Extra

BTW you don't need to use angle brackets with method references since type inference should be able to figure out correct generic type parameter based on context, so

```
Comparator.comparing(Pair::getPathToFile, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
```

should also work fine.